# How to download Games

Tags: games

I have a download limit in my home PC so cannot download games from my home. Can you recommend few games that comes in a .deb package so that I can download them outside and bring them home to download.

Games *like* Max Payne or NFS (not exactly Max payn or NFS) for ubuntu. which I can download as .deb but not synaptic, as I have mentioned that I would download them outside my home and bring the deb home.

thanks

Comment: er... where did you download them from? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good choice is playdeb repo with a lot of games for ubuntu. You can go to website of playdeb find the game that you want and go to home page and download it.

[PlayDeb](http://www.playdeb.net/welcome/)

Answer (score 4):

Games such as Max Payn or NFS are licensed by their owners and because they didn't created an ubuntu version you can't download any .deb after a **legal** purchase.

I however can suggest World of Goo. It costs only 20 bucks and it comes in a .deb package. See http://2dboy.com/games.php.

Furthermore I suggest you to check the following site because it is all about ubuntu games. Be sure to check todays game of the week. It's a free game and I believe downloadable as a .deb. http://www.ubuntugamer.com

Good luck,
Martijn.

Comment: I agree with KYI when it comes to World of Goo. Like my previous suggestion (Machinarium), World of Goo is a puzzle-based game.  Here is the link:  http://2dboy.com/games.php

Answer (score 3):

**Urban Terror**

It is self contained, and would not require additional packages to be downloaded. It has binaries for all major OS in the same package.
Keep note this is a multiplayer game.

Link - http://www.urbanterror.info/news/home/

Answer (score 2):

**Wolfenstein: Enemy Territory**

> http://www.playdeb.net/software/Enemy%20Territory

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a game that runs well on Ubuntu.  Just finished playing it recently:  http://machinarium.net/demo/

Answer (score 0):

You should see [Speed Dreams](http://www.speed-dreams.org/) For NFS alternative.